# Timestamp to complete date format

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, apache-metamodel

We are working on oracle 11g enterprises edition. We are facing issue in getting value of date for type `TIMESTAMPTZ` and `TIMESTAMPLTZ`. We are storing those dates into one csv file using apache metamodel. We are fetching date from database using :

```
 TIMESTAMPLTZ columnValue = (TIMESTAMPLTZ) row.getValues()[pos]; 
 Timestamp timestamp=columnValue.timestampValue(connection,Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()));
 Date dateByTimeStamp=new Date(timestamp.getTime()); 
 Date dateByDateValue = columnValue.dateValue(connection);
 String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a").format(dateByTimeStamp or dateByDateValue );
```

`dateByDateValue` contains date upto yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. eg. 2016-10-12 08:49:30. There is no way to get value of nanoseconds and time zone using this object.

`dateByTimeStamp` object contains **cdate** that have value of date upto nanoseconds and also have time zone. But the value of date time differ because of time zone, but this cdate object contains information regarding nanoseconds precision.

Is there any way to get date in complete format so that the formatted date can directly be used to restore into another oracle db?

Comment: Maybe you have to set the `TimeZone` of the `SimpleDateFormat`?